# How to use formCOntrolName for below data

Tags: angular, angular6, angular5, angular7

I am using ngModel method.. Now I want to create a form using formControlName for this data.

```
 data = {
      "id": "a11",
      "name": "angel",
      "Profiles": [
        {
          "id": "p1",
          "name": "profile1",
          "value": "NONE"
        },
        {
          "id": "p2",
          "name": "profile2",
          "value": "NONE"
        },
        {
          "id": "p3",
          "name": "profile3",
          "value": "NONE"
        },
        {
          "id": "p4",
          "name": "profile4",
          "value": "NONE"
        },
        {
          "id": "p5",
          "name": "profile5",
          "value": "NONE"
        },
        {
      ]
    }
```

From my knowledge I create a structure.

```
  createForm() {
    this.profileFormGroup = this.fb.group({
      id: [''],
      name: [''],
      Profiles: this.fb.array([this.initProfile()])
   });
  }
```

But i got stucked in creating form using formControlName..
[image]

Can anybody help me please???

Comment: Can anybody help me?

Comment: ok @HusseinAkar

Comment: What does initProfile look like and what does your template look like?

Comment: @MikeOne Actually I dont know how to use formGroup method for this condition

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms